# Is access to the request and response objects in Node's http.createServer the result of closure?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

This may be completely obvious, but I want to confirm that the "mechanics" of allowing access via an anonymous or named function within the createServer method to the request and response objects is an example of closure?  That is createServer being the outer function and some other returned function being the inner function that has access to the request and response objects?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: This will be much easier to discuss if you post a snippet. `createServer` itself doesn't have anything to do with `req` and `res`. Those only come into play when a `request` event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they are just simple method arguments. Here is my standard "super clear example of closure" snippet:

```
var tipper = function (percentage) {
  return function tip(total) {
    return total + (total * (percentage / 100));
  };
};

var generous = tipper(20);
var normal = tipper(18);
var stingy = tipper(8);

console.log(generous(24.50), normal(24.50), stingy(24.50));
```

The persistent access that the inner `tip` function has to the `percentage` variable, even after the outer `tipper` function has returned, is closure.